# distance makes my iterator "freeze"

Tags: c++, iterator

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream fin_fout("some.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> beg(fin_fout),end;
    std::distance(beg,end);//if this line is commented out it works fine but not if is uncommented
    while (beg != end)
    {
      cout << *beg;
      ++beg;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete code that can be compiled and run.

Comment: std:distance returns a value. Is this intentional that you don't use that value?

Comment: @Power just for this example.

Answer (score 15):

`distance` on an input iterator will repeatedly call `operator++`. However, this operation *invalidates* all copies of the iterator, because they all refer to the same underlying stream

This is logical: consider what the iterator represents: the current state of the input stream. As soon as you advance the iterator, that state changes. All other iterators representing the old state are therefore now referring to a state that no longer exists.

This is why you see this behaviour.

Getting a distance from two stream operators is moreover not a meaningful operation since streams don’t have a fixed *length*: streams represent transient state.

Comment: any idea why? It operates on copies, and second question, any way to get difference between those iterators and then being able to use them? But it is so unnatural behaviour.

Comment: @smallB: No, you can't copy a stream, and so a stream iterator does not operate on copies. It operates on the stream itself. And so, every `operator++` call extracts the *next* item in the stream. It changes the stream itself, and so it invalidates any other iterators pointing to the stream. In a stream, only two positions make sense: an iterator can point at the *current* element, or it may point "past" the stream (the *end* iterator). The distance between the two is simply not defined. (how much would I have to read from stdin to reach the end of the stream?)

Comment: @smallB No, it doesn’t operate on copies, it refers to the same underlying stream. You cannot copy a stream. And no, there is no way to get the difference, the operation isn’t meaningful since a stream has no length.

Comment: @jalf and Konrad, cannot agree with both of you on the length of stream business. If a have a file (as I have and checked) with a 200 numbers, each on new line in this file, the difference between beg and end gives me 200; and end of the file can be thought as the end of the input stream, can't it?

Comment: @smallB You cannot generalise this case. For example, `/dev/random` is a file *without end*. Or consider network streams where the size of the resource isn’t known to the local computer, or a log file that is currently being written to. In general, determining the length of a file stream just isn’t possible. There are special cases (such as yours) but the stream iterator interface caters to the general case, not the special case. There are other ways to determine the length of a fixed file, but not via iterators.

Comment: @smallB: we're not talking about files, we're talking about streams. Show me a mechanism to get the distance from `std::cout` to, uh, the end of `std::cout`. ;) If you want to iterate over a file *specifically*, you could use memory mapping, for example. Then a pair of pointers will work as ordinary random-access iterators. But as long as you're going through a stream, you suffer all the limitations that a stream has.

Comment: @jalf See my comment; it’s true even for ordinary files.

Comment: @Konrad: kind of. Ordinary files are typically (at least on Windows) locked when you read from them. And even if not, you can always get the *current* size and position from a file. So in practice, the distance *could* be determined for files. If your iterators operated on the file directly, rather than on a stream interface

Comment: @smallB There's no problem with using `distance` on an `istream_iterator`.  Doing so, however, invalidates the iterators you passed it as arguments, and means that any further use of them is undefined behavior.  (This is what input iterator means.)  In practice, with `istream_iterator`, the end iterator will not be affected, and the other iterator will encounter end of file as soon as it is incremented.  (But this is an artifact of how `istream_iterator` is typically implemented; it's still undefined behavior.)

Comment: @Konrad: this begs the question --> since all iterators are supposed to advertise their kinds (`iterator_traits<>::category` or something like this) why isn't distance specialized to trigger a compile-time error on `input_iterator` and `output_iterator` kinds ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, as others have said you *can* call `distance` with input iterators, and sometimes you even get the right result. That said, I don’t know when this is ever useful and why it’s allowed. Raising a compile error would IMHO be superior.